# order a list of numbers from given list without built-in sort, copy

Tags: python, sorting, pseudocode

in python i try to implement my code in a way that it does basically the same thing as sorted(lst) without using sorted(lst) or var = lst.copy() but i just can't figure it out how to work it that way and following exactly the way as it is written in the pseudo code.

can someone please help me ?

my assesment is:

Below is the pseudocode of a sorting algorithm:

1. Starting from the beginning of a list,
   compare each element with its next neighbor.
2. If the element is larger than its next neighbour, change them places.
3. Go through the list to the end.
4. If there have been any mix-ups at step 2,go to step 1

my code right now :

```
    lst_sorted = lst.copy()
    has_swapped = True
    while has_swapped:
        has_swapped = False
        for i in range(len(lst_sorted) - 1):
            a = lst_sorted[i]
            b = lst_sorted[i + 1]
            if b < a:
                lst_sorted[i] = b
                lst_sorted[i + 1] = a
                has_swapped = True
    return lst_sorted
```

the test code:

```
    def test_my_sort():
        lst_test = random.choices(range(-99, 100), k=6)
        lst_copy = lst_test.copy()
        lst_output = my_sort(lst_test)

        assert lst_copy == lst_test, "Error: my_sort (lst) changes the contents of list lst"
        assert lst_output == sorted(lst_test), \
            f "Error: my_sort ({lst_test}) returns {lst_output} instead of {sorted (lst_test)}"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            test_my_sort()
            print("Your my_sort () function works fine!")
```

Answer (score 1):

When submitting questions it is helpful to identify what in particular you have a question about instead of a vague request. Whether that's an error code you are getting or a particular unexpected response.

Before even looking at your sort function There are a couple things in your pasted code that need to be fixed prior to it running correctly. You have a try statement without a corresponding except in your main. Also, I am assuming you have

```
import random
```

somewhere above your code but didn't paste it?

The sort function you have created both looks and runs correctly for me. I would recommend fixing the areas I've mentioned above if needed, and modifying your question with what particularly you are stuck on.

Comment: The ''my code" is written by me and the "test code" is what my professor gave me and i am not allowed to edit that part and the result must be that python is printing your function is working correctly as written under the test code

Comment: @MehmetBayram  is that really the code that your professor give you? as is it would not even compile/load, as @LaBeaux mention is missing the `except` to the `try`, the `f "Error...` should be `f"Error...` (notice the space between the f and ") and the import is missing

Comment: the `f` is needed, but it needs to be directly next to the string

Comment: I also did not note, make sure you define your function with a name. I see you have a return statement at the bottom of your block of code, but you did not indicate a function declaration e.g. `def my_sort(lst_tst)` above it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning python, so this is probably not the best way, but it seems to work:

```
def my_sort(lst):
    randHolder = []
    for ele in range(len(lst)):
        mini = min(lst)
        giveIndex = lst.index(mini)
        popped = lst.pop(giveIndex)
        randHolder.append(popped)
    lst = randHolder
    return lst
```